# Does the future works policy apply to this question?

Tags: closing-questions, discussion

The question [Does this organization still exist?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186543/51226) was closed, with a voter citing the future works policy. However, I fail to see how said policy applies. The question is not about a future work, it's about the backstory to a released film. Not currently having a definitive answer (which is not certain in this case) is not the same as being about a future work, and as outlined [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3014/51226), is not a valid reason to close the question.

Comment: To me it looks like any information relating to that will be revealed in the future and so is FWP.

Comment: You seem to be conflating two ideas. The point you mention is quite clearly not revealed in the film in question, as everyone who has seen the film will know. It is however a point in an ongoing film series where more information is revealed on a regular basis. Given this point of information certainly can be known to have been "not revealed", if it is revealed we must await a future work and as such the question has been closed according to said policy. The policy you cite, while not explicit, imo works for finished stories, there is unlikely to be a canon answer and "We don't know"....

Comment: Is the best answer you'll get in that situation.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot That is not how the future works policy is meant to be used. Every problematic question listed [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187/51226) is clearly either asking about a specific unreleased work, or a hypothetical future work. The question being discussed does neither, has it is asking about the backstory to a released film.

Comment: @RogueJedi The question may be asking about the back story but the answer is related to a future work. As such that is why it has been closed.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot Which future work is it related to?

Comment: @RogueJedi Avengers 4, GotG 3 will likely have some potential information in them.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot Again, I see no evidence that the policy makes *any* mention that questions without an answer should be closed because they *might* be answered at some point in the future.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that this is quite _clearly_ outlined in the policy at hand. *Question asked. - Question is closed as "not ready yet" (frankly this deserves a special offtopic choice IMHO). This prevents any bad answers from being posted. - Months/years later, correct canon answer is published*

Comment: @edlothiad The question in question is not "not ready yet." It pertains to a released work. Closing it is just failing to follow the 'Questions without answers" policy under the disguise of the Future Works Policy.

Comment: @Edlothiad You say *"we don't know" is the best answer you'll get* as if that's a bad thing, but questions to which the answer is "we don't know" are perfectly acceptable in general - even if they're about a non-static body of canon, where any "we don't know" is technically "we don't know but we might in the future".

Comment: @Randal'Thor I was not implying it was a bad thing, for certain works it is the best answer you'll get, be it good or bad, you won't find a true answer to your question. In non-static canons, I'm personally of the opinion, as are all the voters who voted on the FWP meta, that questions where a canon answer will likely come up should be put on hold as their answer hasn't revealed yet but will likely be addressed in a future work. We have on many occasions done this exact procedure. It is quite common practice on this site.

Comment: @Edlothiad That "likely" is the sticking point, I think. Taking *Doctor Who* as an example universe (because its canon is constantly expanding and I'm familiar with it): a question like "what is the Doctor's name?" might have been closed as FW if it had been posted shortly before the episode "The Name of the Doctor" was released, but in general it's certainly a valid question about the show, even though the answer is "we don't know (and technically might find out in a later episode)".

Comment: @Edlothiad Also, don't presume to speak for "all the voters who voted on the FWP meta". Lecturing more experienced users about what "is quite common practice on this site" also comes off as rude, and I've already deleted one of your earlier comments here for being an ad-hominem attack.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I didn't think I was using a lecturing tone, nor did I intend to come off as rude. Although the same could be said about claiming "experience" based purely by time on site. Either way, a question being put on hold due to the FWP does not make it a bad question. The question wasn't closed because it doesn't fit the scope of the site, or because it's off-topic. It's merely to preserve the question from getting a string of either speculative answers, or a "We don't know" answer, which has a very high likelihood of being rendered wrong in a rather short period of time.

Comment: I personally don't see why an answer that will almost certainly be wrong would be wanted to a question and would aid a user in reaching various privilege levels when posting incorrect content. If it is the communities wish to re-open it then so be it. It is not my question. If the community disagrees with the FWP as it exists then it should be revisited.

Comment: @Randal'Thor `even though the answer is "we don't know (and technically might find out in a later episode)"` I'd ask then, what is the point of the future-works policy if every question can be answered with "we don't know... yet"? Do you think it's time to revisit that policy?

Comment: @Möoz The point of the FWP is to close questions which are *about* FWs, or where the answer will *clearly* be revealed in FWs. We don't close every question where the answer is "we don't know" and the canon is still incomplete. Otherwise there'd be a hell of a lot more closed *Doctor Who* questions.

Comment: You know it'd be more helpful if someone wrote an answer as an answer, instead of a comment, and then the answer could be fleshed out based on ensuing commentary.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76827/discussion-on-question-by-rogue-jedi-does-the-future-works-policy-apply-to-this) for further discussion.

Comment: [This comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based#comment37765_5188) in the discussion under the FW policy post makes a very clear statement by one of the oldest active users on the site about the functions of that policy, in particular with the film universe in question.

Comment: @CreationEdge I think the commentary here helped me to solidify my thoughts into a coherent answer :-)

Comment: As one of the people involved in the formation of the FWP, I've gotta say, you guys trying to close everything as FW are turning the policy into something far broader than we had originally intended.

Comment: @phantom42: This is the proximate cause of the iron law of bureaucracy: As soon as you have a policy that allows doing X, people will try to use it to do Y.  So you need another policy to prohibit Y, which people try to use to prohibit Z...

Answer (score 6):

<sup>*Disclaimer: I don't know anything about the Marvel universe. This is a general discussion of the future works policy.*</sup>

---

I think there's a continuum of different types of question to be considered here.

1. At one end of the scale we have **questions explicitly about future works**. If someone asks now about what will happen in Star Wars Episode IX, that question should be closed under the Future Works Policy and reopened once it's answerable.
2. At the other end of the scale are **questions with unknown answer and closed canon**. If someone asks about the state of the realm in Gondor a hundred years after Aragorn's death (<sub><sup>I'm trying to think of a LotR question which isn't answered somewhere in the massive canon!</sup></sub>), then the answer might be "we don't know", but [that's not enough reason to close](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3014/31394), and it would also be unreasonable to close under the Future Works Policy as there's no reason to think any further canon is forthcoming.

In between these two extremes lie **questions with unknown answer and incomplete canon.** If the answer to a general question about some universe is unknown *now*, but might be revealed in a future work set in that universe ... well, that "might" is where things get sticky.

- Sometimes it might be *very clear* that the answer will only become known after the release of some future work. If you ask about the backstory of a character appearing in the first book of a series, and it's clear from how the book ends that that backstory will be revealed in the second book ... then I could see closing the question under the Future Works Policy.
- Sometimes there might be *no reason to believe* that the answer will be revealed in future works. Take this question, for example: [What is the Doctor's real name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93570/31394) The answer is unknown, and *could* in theory be revealed in a future episode, but given the role the *question* plays in the story, I very much doubt it. (Pertinent information *has* been revealed in new episodes as the show goes on, though, and this has been edited into the accepted answer as appropriate.)

Where disputes arise, then, is when **people disagree on *how likely it is* that the answer will be revealed in future works.** The thing about the future is that we never know for sure what will happen there, so there's often room for debate. Without knowing anything about Marvel, I think that's what's going on with your question: the close-voters think the answer *clearly* lies in future canon, while the reopen-voters think that's not so clear and the question can be validly answered from current canon.

Comment: So, does the future-works policy apply or nah?

Comment: What's certainly clear is the question can _not_ be answered from current canon. It was addressed in a line and never mentioned again, the answer would be "We don't know" and no additional text, because anything else would be purely made-up fan-fiction. An excellent summary of the issue at hand though.

Comment: @Edlothiad As you know, "We don't know" is an acceptable answer, and it [can often be fleshed out](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11330/31394) with something much better than "purely made-up fan-fiction". I'd be surprised if it's impossible to say more than three words in a reasonable answer to this question. In fact, if as you say it's "addressed in a line", then wouldn't quoting that line and the fact that it's never mentioned again be a necessary part of a full answer?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I invite you to try. Any answer could look at what Thanos did to the Asgardians (we don't know, we just saw dead bodies), the people of Knowhere (we don't know we just saw destruction) or he may have simply teleported in and teleported out. Maybe he killed a guard. Maybe he killed everyone. Maybe he had his minions fly in on a donut, kill some people and then fly out on a donut. Maybe he had his army of outriders kill everyone on the planet and he just waltzed in. We have no idea what happened, I could come up with another score of scenarios, each as likely as the last.

Comment: [cont] Now you may say "see more than 3 words" but all of those are purely made up scenarios, which all could've happened or none. They're purely based on my opinion and speculation and nothing else. In that case, the question would be better preserved for when the information is released in a future work.

Comment: "we don't know, but as stated in *infinity war*, thanos' MO is to only kill half of the population. it is entirely possible that a sizable portion of the novacorps survived and continues to operate".  is that more than three words based on informed speculation?