# Are theoretical questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

In the *Wheel of Time* series, there's an item called an A'dam which creates a sort of link between two women who can channel. I'd like to ask a theoretical question about the A'dam(The question is "Can the bracelet be modified to work with other bracelets to make linking easier?").

Are these theoretical questions on topic?

Comment: Yes, you are not required to have read a work at all to ask questions about it. Relevant meta, possibly dupe: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/i-havent-read-the-book-watched-the-movie-may-i-ask-a-question-about-it

Comment: @Edlothiad: I've edited my question. The future works part really had no bearing on what I wanted to ask, but I had put it there to explain that though the question and answer may be only be a theoretical to me at the time of reading, future works may or may not(this is the key) have a real answer. What I'd really meant was more of  a "Can I ask a question about X being possible?"

Comment: I see, I've retracted my close vote, although the logic seems to be the same, in my opinion. I'm also certain this meta exist, I will dig it out later :)

Answer (score 5):

I can't see why this question *wouldn't* be on-topic. We have a great many questions of the form "can X be done in this particular work of sci-fi/fantasy?", including several in the WoT tag:

- [Suicide by balefire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95573/suicide-by-balefire?s=3|62.4957)
- [What if two people balefire each other at the same time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119898/what-if-two-people-balefire-each-other-at-the-same-time?s=7|47.3766)

Many ["what if" questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+if%22+is%3Aq) are still answerable and therefore not close-worthy:

- If the question is trivially answered in one of the later books of the series, then it may be *downvoted* (although this is very hard to predict) but it shouldn't be *closed* - it's perfectly answerable and on-topic, even if 'obvious' to someone who's finished the series.
- If the question isn't explicitly answered anywhere in the series, then it may have been answered in other canon material (for WoT, there are a lot of author interviews), or it may be deducible from other in-universe properties of the item in question, or the answer may simply be ["we don't know"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11329/31394).

Also, it's [perfectly fine](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/i-havent-read-the-book-watched-the-movie-may-i-ask-a-question-about-it) to ask questions about a series you're still in the middle of reading. That's one of the things this site is here for. Be warned though: if such a question is trivially answered in a later book in the series, it may get downvoted, as noted above.

Comment: So you're agreeing with the consensus in the link post? It should then be a dupe?

Comment: @Edlothiad It may be a dupe, but I didn't think it was a clear enough one to modhammer (this isn't just "haven't read the series", but "currently in the *middle* of reading the series"). Feel free to VTC and see what people think.

Comment: They seem to be pretty much the same imo

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned I'm reading the series, it has no bearing on the real question i wanted to ask. Edited it for clarification.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks OK, edited my answer, but a lot of it still applies. TL;DR: this question sounds fine.

Answer (score 2):

**On-topic, but still may be opinion based**

What it depends on is if there is enough canon information to give a relatively accurate answer supported by the work or by word-of-god statements.

I have seen tons of "theoretical" questions. Some stay open, some get closed.  However, there is [no requirement](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/i-havent-read-the-book-watched-the-movie-may-i-ask-a-question-about-it) that you have had to read/watched a work to ask questions on it. So what you will want to strive for is writing a good concise question that shows some level of research.

After that, the community decides... The voting on the question will be your guide. My advice would be to know this risk (down-votes, closure) before asking such a question.

Comment: A question doesn't become POB just because there isn't enough canon information to give a definite answer. See [your own meta about "we don't know" answers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11330/31394), and its dupe targets [Are questions without enough data 'unanswerable'?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1699/31394) and [Should all questions without explicit canon answers be closed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3014/31394)

Comment: @Randal'Thor hence why I included that the community decided. By this logic we should never close a question as POB.

Comment: No, there are plenty of *valid* reasons to close a question as POB. I can't see what logic you're using to get from "this particular thing doesn't make a question POB" to "nothing should ever be closed as POB".

Comment: @Randal'Thor All question can have a "We don't know answer". I am not suggesting an answer need a direct canon answer. It needs to show effort though, as all questions and answers do.